# Not able to start hive on cloudera vm

Tags: hive, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm, hive-metastore

I am beginner to Big data systems. 
I have installed Cloudera quick start vm-5.13.0 in my Oracle Virtual Box.
I issued following command to start hive.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hive
```

But getting following error and hive is not started.
It seems like it is not able to connect with Hive metastore but I haven't made any changes in the VM installation. 
Please let me know any manual changes I need to start hive.

Thanks.

```
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.setupAuth(SessionState.java:833)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.getAuthorizationMode(SessionState.java:1679)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.isAuthorizationModeV2(SessionState.java:1690)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.processors.CommandUtil.authorizeCommand(CommandUtil.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.processors.AddResourceProcessor.run(AddResourceProcessor.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processInitFiles(CliDriver.java:472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:723)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:634)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getAuthorizeProviderManager(HiveUtils.java:391)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.setupAuth(SessionState.java:810)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.HiveAuthorizationProviderBase.setConf(HiveAuthorizationProviderBase.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getAuthorizeProviderManager(HiveUtils.java:388)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.DefaultHiveAuthorizationProvider.init(DefaultHiveAuthorizationProvider.java:29)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.HiveAuthorizationProviderBase.setConf(HiveAuthorizationProviderBase.java:112)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3643)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:215)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1560)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: MetaException(message:Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3643)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.DefaultHiveAuthorizationProvider.init(DefaultHiveAuthorizationProvider.java:29)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.HiveAuthorizationProviderBase.setConf(HiveAuthorizationProviderBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getAuthorizeProviderManager(HiveUtils.java:388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.setupAuth(SessionState.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.getAuthorizationMode(SessionState.java:1679)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.isAuthorizationModeV2(SessionState.java:1690)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.processors.CommandUtil.authorizeCommand(CommandUtil.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.processors.AddResourceProcessor.run(AddResourceProcessor.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processInitFiles(CliDriver.java:472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:723)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:634)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:221)
    ... 45 more
)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:512)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: Hive CLient is deprecated and you should be using beeline instead of Hive. Can you check if using beeline client throws the same error?

Comment: I got following error with beeline command: [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://quickstart:10000/default -n admin -d org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://quickstart:10000/default
Could not open connection to the HS2 server. Please check the server URI and if the URI is correct, then ask the administrator to check the server status.
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://quickstart:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (state=08S01,code=0)
Beeline version 1.1.0-cdh5.13.0 by Apache Hive

Comment: I changed metastore db username from 'hive' to 'root' in hive-site.xml. Now I am able to connect to hive using 'hive' command. Although I have given all privileges to 'hive' metastore was failing to start with "Connection Refused" error.